# Gradle IDE (Eclipse) Documentation

Tags: eclipse, scala, gradle, spring-tool-suite, gradle-eclipse

I am learning Gradle and have found my way around the normal use case. But now I have to step into integration with Eclipse (specifically STS) and need to learn more about how "Gradle projects" are imported into Eclipse (without having to generate the .project files using the inverse - Eclipse plugin for Gradle). By just attempting it I discovered that it did import my projects. However, projects written in Scala (some are pure Java, some Scala, some mixed) were not recognized and applied as Scala projects. In fact, Eclipse attempted to compile ".scala" files as if they were ".java" somehow and obviously failed miserably.

Tried Googling around to find more documentation on Eclipse integration but this appears to be significantly obscured by the "eclipse plugin" for Gradle in search results. Can someone, please, point me at documentation, if available, or provide at least some guidance with respect to my problem above...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> without having to generate the .project files using the inverse - Eclipse plugin for Gradle

Does this mean that you **don't** want to apply the Eclipse plugin in your Gradle project? Can I ask why? My experience of it has been very positive.

Here's what I've done in such cases:

- apply the Eclipse plugin in my Gradle project (*apply plugin: 'eclipse'*)
- run the 'eclipse' Gradle task (*gradle eclipse*)
- in Eclipse, do *File>Import...>Existing projects into workspace* and navigate to the Gradle project directory (or the root directory of a multi-project structure); (don't check *Copy projects into workspace*)

If the Gradle project also applies the Java plugin, you'll get a .project file that declares a javanature and refers to the javabuilder, and a .classpath file will also be generated. If not, you'll just get a vanilla .project file. The Gradle documentation makes it sound very much as if a similar thing applies in the case of the Scala plugin: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#N12EC0. Does this not work for you?

Comment: I *can* apply the Eclipse plugin in my Gradle project but I can't stop there. I am tasked with making it trivial for developers (new and old) to set up their dev environment - any one step less is good. 

Furthermore, that does not address updating dependencies from Eclipse.  The hope was that I will just be able to tell developers to import the Gradle project into Eclipse and be done with it. That works, but only partially.

Honestly, didn't even try to apply the Eclipse plugin yet (as I was hoping for the other approach) ... will try and report.

Comment: Step #1 - Projects imported and Scala ones were properly recognized it seems (waiting for the build to complete to verify)...

Comment: Step #2 - This almost worked... and I see Gradle functionality in Eclipse even though the projects were not imported via "Import Gradle...". Need to figure out how to add more "builders" to the project - as one project depends on an actual jar from another (that Eclipse does not generate, that jar is a Scala compiler plugin and it is only accepted in a jar form - classes folder is insufficient)...

Still, why doesn't importing Gradle projects work using Gradle IDE?

Comment: I think it's possible that we're talking partly at cross-purposes, but I think you need to apply the eclipse plugin (as well as applying the appropriate language plugin, java/scala). Then when you do "Import Gradle..." you have the option to run Gradle targets e.g. cleanEclipse, eclipse at the same time, which should be selected so that the .project/.classpath files are generated at this point. I presume this is a Gradle multiproject build?

Comment: Yes, this is multi-project. I am now facing some issues with this approach (not saying that any other is better). For example, I don't have (or know about) sufficient control over how *.project and *.prefs files are created so I can't set up Scala compiler options. So, temporarily, I don't create them using Gradle (not running 'eclipse' any more but only 'eclipseClasspath'. And because I am using GWT and i have to insert some stuff to be first in that path, I have trouble even with that...

Comment: I've had some success with manipulating the results of the eclipse task, rather like this: `eclipse {
 project.file {
  whenMerged {

   project ->
    project.natures.add( 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature' )
    project.buildCommands.add( name: 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder' )
  }
 }
}`

Comment: (sorry about the format, comments are quite limited in that respect)